# Quick retrieval of same data with multi dimensions

Tags: caching, elasticsearch, search, database-indexes, nosql

Here is my case.I have fields of a user like name,phone,email,city,country,other user attributes. If I search by name or phone or email ,I need to get all users details who are satisfying those conditions in very short time.As far as I know,To implement this in a key value cache, I need to have same data with different key.

My current plan of implementing is as follows

All the following info are stored in my cache
**User level complete data**
unique_user_id(XXX) :{name:abc, phone:12345, email:abc@gmail.com..etc}
unique_user_id(YYY) :{name:def, phone:67891, email:def@gmail.com..etc}
**Email level info**
abc@gmail.com : XXX
def@gmail..com : YYY
**Name level info**
abc : XXX
def : YYY
**Phone level info**
12345 : XXX
67891 : YYY

If I search with email, I query 'Email level info' and get the unique user id and query the 'User level info' for user details. Here I have duplicated data for each type of possible key.I do not want to duplicate data. I want to have single key value for each user.
Is there any better way than key value caches where data stored should be minimal and response time is very less. I am okay to go with database along with hash indexing kind of stuff.Please suggest an appropriate software for this.

I have never used caches. Please bear with my understanding and language

Comment: A key-value cache would only work if the secondary indexes are guaranteed to be unique (allowing a load on a cache miss). Otherwise you need the full dataset, so querying a database or a search engine is preferred. Consider using a search engine like ElasticSearch or a hosted one like [Algolia](http://www.algolia.com).

Comment: I never used a elastic search. How about using nosql stores like cassandra or HBase?

Comment: NoSQL usually requires precomputing index tables for fast queries, so they aren't good for ad hoc queries. SQL is good for simple search and then a real search engine for more complex scenarios, especially when speed matters. I usually start with SQL until the problem domain is flushed out, transitioning to NoSQL and a search engine when deemed appropriate. I only start with NoSQL if that's readily available and I know the constraints to design around.